# Responding to the return button

Tags: iphone

I'd like to respond to a touch on the return button of the virtual keyboard.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious but it looks like I should set a notification for "textFieldShouldReturn:" and have that call some return key handler.  Is this the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm... kinda.

Look at [the text field's delegate](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/06_ImplementingController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH8-SW3) section of Apple's "Your First iPhone Application" doc.

Comment: Okay, not sure how I missed this.  Looks like the delegate can respond to a "textFieldShouldReturn:" method.  Thanks!